# How can I effectively adhere things to scratchboard?

Tags: adhesives, scratch-art

I want to glue cut-out pieces from a shiny silvery Bristol board onto scratch art paper (or scratchboard). I also want to adhere flowers (I haven't figured out whether to used dried or fake yet) to the board.

The problem I'm facing is that the scratchboard has a very smooth painted surface. Without the rough texture of paper, I'm worried my items will not properly adhere.

Is there a type of glue, or technique for gluing items to a very smooth surface like scratch board?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find a **hot glue gun** very versatile and forgiving for these types of applications. And it works phenomenally well for sticking irregularly-shaped items to smooth surfaces.

[image]

Product Search: **[Hot Glue Gun](https://www.google.com/search?q=hot+glue+gun&biw=2558&bih=1437&tbm=shop&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwier9DjuuzPAhXKbj4KHRJmCT8Q_AUIBigB&dpr=1)**

Comment: I think you are right and this will end up being the most effective method. I wasn't sure if some sort of epoxy would be necessary.

Comment: the hot glue gun worked perfectly. Thank you for your suggestion :)